# Add custom "Tab" to experience profile Tabs

Tags: experience-profile

I'm extending the sitecore experience profile to add a custom tab to display my custom events and facets. i'm following this article:
https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2016/04/19/extending-sitecore-experience-profile-speak-app/comment-page-1/#comment-730 
However i'm stuck at the step of adding renderings to the "Custom Tab" layout.
[image]

or even when trying to edit any of the already existing tabs layout. i always get the following error[image]

i Can't add the placeholders and and DataSource to the new tab i just created.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Are you using [Sitecore Rocks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakobChristensen.SitecoreRocks) to edit the presentation details of that item? I don't think you can do it in Sitecore directly.

Comment: @ Dan Sinclair  yes i was trying to do it from sitecore directly. How can i use Sitecore Rocks and connect it to my Sitecore instance database?

Comment: I would recommend following the steps in the article you linked. The introduction references Sitecore Rocks and has a link to download and install it. Once it's installed, you can connect it to your Sitecore instance.

Comment: This involves a many step process if you do this SPEAK way. Instead, you can do this using the EPExpressTab which allows you to add a custom tab to the contact in the experience profile. You can find all the documentation and code at https://github.com/JeffDarchuk/EPExpressTab NuGet package for this module is also available https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPExpressTab/

Comment: Without the links, this answer equates to exactly nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In order to design a SPEAK application (or parts of a SPEAK application), you will need Sitecore Rocks. Sitecore has a good reference for this:

https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/development/using_visual_studio_and_sitecore_rocks

From the documentation:

> You use Sitecore Rocks to develop exclusively for SPEAK applications. You cannot use the Content Editor or other related tools. This topic explains how to get started using Sitecore Rocks for SPEAK development.

## To set up Sitecore Rocks to connect to your Sitecore instance

> 1. In Sitecore Rocks, in Sitecore Explorer, right-click Connections.
>
>    [image: sitecore explorer]
> 2. In the Connection dialog box, in the Host Name field, select the Sitecore installation, and then click OK.
>
>    [image: web service config]
> 3. If this dialog appears, click Yes:
>
>    [image: dialog]
> 4. In the Update Server Components dialog, click Update All:
>
>    [image: update server components dialog]
>
> You can now explore a Sitecore installation with the Sitecore Explorer
>
> [image: sitecore explorer after setup]